# Substitute with backslash in sed

Tags: sed

I want to replace `word` with `\word{sth}` with sed.
I type in

`sed -i s@word@\\word{sth}`

but i am getting is word{sth} instead of \word{sth}

I tried with 1 slash also in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add four backslashes.

you need two to escape the backslash by the terminal, and two to escape it for sed. 2*2=4.

```
$ echo word|sed s@word@\\\\word{sth}@gi
\word{sth}
```

Comment: @curious no need to be crazy. Just see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider enclosing `sed` expression with single-quotes `'`

```
sed -i 's@word@\\word{sth}@' file
```